# Nginx simple redirect of products from old to new category

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm making redirects of products from old to new category.

I've managed to make it work with following rule:

```
rewrite ^/old-category/(.*) /new-category/$1;
```

But I want to know when should I use "end line" sign $ and what's the difference with it or without it in my case. For example:

```
rewrite ^/old-category/(.*)$ /new-category/$1;
```

Also I want to redirect users if they simply write old category name (without products), should I create a new rule just for category redirect or I can edit the current rule above to work in both cases.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering your questions in order...

This

```
rewrite ^/old-category/(.*) /new-category/$1;
```

and this

```
rewrite ^/old-category/(.*)$ /new-category/$1;
```

*as written* are equivalent. The `.*` rule matches 0 or more of "everything", so the `$` is redundant/not really needed.

The `$` terminator is useful when you want to match strings that end in a *specific way*, for example

```
rewrite ^/old-category/(.*)\.php$ /new-category/$1;
```

to rewrite *only PHP files*.

As for your second question, if I understood correctly, you want to redirect this

```
http://example.com/old-category/
```

to this

```
http://example.com/new-category/
```

If that's so, it's already done by the `rewrite` rule, as `.*` matches **ZERO** or more characters.

Comment: Good question, good answer. So many people set the $ by default (or leave it out by default) without thinking about what it actually means. Every time I see (.*)$ I cringe. I didn't try it but it might actually be that leaving out the $ in this case could have a *slightly* better performance as it's another rule regex has to check for. Would be interesting to get an answer to that question :D